# convert date and time from onetimezone to anothertimezone in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 $fromTz=">America/chicago"; //Time zone for UM6 
 $toTz="America/Adak" ;//Time Zone for UM4
 $date = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($fromTz));
 echo "<br>America/chicago Time ".$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($toTz));
 $time= $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 echo "<br>Time For $toTz ".$time;
```

I have convert the date and time from onetimezone to another timezone in php.

I want to convert UM6 To UM4,UM5,UM7,UM8

but i don'nt know the value of UM5,UM7 and UM8 
like UM4="America/Adak"

So what the value for UM5,UM7 and UM8

Answer (score 0):

use this, use this function for convert time zone.

```
function converTotimezone($time="",$toTz='',$fromTz=''){   
    // timezone by php friendly values
    $date = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($fromTz));
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($toTz));
    $time= $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    return $time;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code but what the timezone value for UM8 and UM7

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$dateTime="2017-11-02T00:00:00.000Z";
date_default_timezone_set('America/chicago'); 
$timeZoneFrom="America/chicago";
$date = new DateTime($dateTime, new DateTimeZone($timeZoneFrom));
$time_zoneTo="America/Adak"; 
$date= $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($time_zoneTo));
print_r($date);
or echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); `
```